# How to force a function to return 'unit' in Rescript?

Tags: rescript

I am trying to simulate a side effect of writing to DB with rescript.

So I want to push the data in an array when calling `repository.add`. `Js.Array.push` returns an `int`, which I do not care about. I would like to force to return `unit` so that my signature shows `unit` which lets me know immediately that this function produces a side effect.

Here is the code ([and a playground here](https://rescript-lang.org/try?code=LYewJgrgNgpgBABRgJwM4gHZwLxwN4BQccALgJ4AO8MGJAluTvkXAJABmdaJAcgIbAYALjioSyOhgDmLAL4sW5KnGQwKIVAxDIyTQsWJ8wYETXqNsAPjgQMDADQtiUmCQCCUKCNsMc1vsjIfGQAPGYMZJZyBArEsCRwAMaqfCQwAEpqGlo6TAAUAJQiquqaJNq6VszErPGi5UEuIgFBoeHk1rgA2gC6TnD9%20gasRiZw7ZXWQwYzcABSqAB0boHBixQQqAAWeRP29dp8LgX9s3CFBKwGso5nrC7uniKFfgeNMP3yxPLyQA)):

```ml
module Person = {
  type entity = {
    firstName: string
  }
  
  type repository = {
    add: entity => unit,
    getAll: unit => array<entity>
  }

  
  let createRepository = (): repository => {
    let storage: array<entity> = []
    
    {
        add: entity => {
          Js.Array.push(entity, storage)  // This has type: int -> Somewhere wanted: unit
          ()         // how to force to return 'unit' there ?
       },
        getAll: () => storage
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function will return `unit` if you return `()`, as you do. That isn't really the problem here. The reason the compiler complains is that you're implicitly ignoring the value returned by `Js.Array.push`, which is usually a mistake. You can shut the compiler up by *explicitly* ignoring it:

```ml
let _: int = Js.Array.push(entity, storage)
```

Edit: I'd also add that you might want to consider using a data structure and API that is more suited for the paradigm. I'd probably use a `list` and make `storage` a `ref<list>` instead, but it depends a bit on what else you're going to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A list may be better, but as I may access the storage with `array.filter.find(...)` (not the head or tail), I thought array where more suited...

Comment: There's `filter` and `find` for `list` as well. In general I only use arrays if I need either indexed access or direct interaction with bindings that take or return arrays.